# Python: Finding the product of randomly generated integers

Tags: python, function, dice

one more question. I am a first year CS student who has to do this on paper, so I am not able to import any programs to solve the problem.

I have been asked to create a psuedo-random set of integers, and then to multiply the products of the integers using a function def product (n). I know this code is really wrong but I'm not really sure what to do at all! Here is what I have so far:

```
def product(n):
    product = j*i
for j in range (20):
    i=random.randrange(1,4,1)
    print ("The set of numbers is", i)
```

Comment: What is `n` representing?

Comment: Why would you multiply two numbers before you have them? Do you understand that programs are generally executed in the order their lines are written?

Comment: I've only been in this class for 3 weeks and I have no idea what I'm doing... Sorry, I'm dumbfounded by this problem. :(

Comment: your code is having bad indentation. unused variable n, undefined i.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the range for the integers, but I think this does what you want:

```
import random

def product(n):
  lower_bound = 1
  upper_bound = 10
  result = 1
  for i in range(n):
    result *= random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound)
  return result
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

```
import random
def product(n):
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,(random.randint(1,3) for i in xrange(n)))
```

Several things:

1. you can't really generate random numbers without importing or writing your own pseudorandom generator
2. look up [reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce).  It's probably the preferred method here.
3. if you can import the `operator` module, use `operator.mul` instead of `lambda x,y:x*y`

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is the number of generated numbers:

```
import random
def product(n):
    random_list = [random.randint(0,n) for r in xrange(n)]
    return reduce(lambda x,y : x*y,  random_list)
```

Comment: You could also use `reduce(operator.mul, ...)`

Comment: Good comment, but since he is new, I want to be more clear.
reduce + lambda + list comprehension...

Answer (score 0):

What do you want? Multiply Integers and display their products? See this :

```
def product(numberOfIntegers) :
   finalResult = 1
   for i in range(1,numberOfIntegers) :
      randomNumber = random.randrange(1,4,1)
      finalResult = finalResult * randomNumber
   return finalResult
```